# Determine if file is still in transfer

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Im looking to use powershell to handle several file transfers via SFTP, but I want to ensure the files set to transfer are complete in the original location. However, using something like

`$file.Length`

or

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $file | Format-list -Property * -Force
```

Seems to return the complete file size that gets transferred with the header, and not the current file size in the location. IE, if a file of size 4gb is transfering in, with only 2gb transfered, both methods will return saying the file size is 4gb.

How do I check the actual file size at the time of the check, or are there other methods of checking file stability prior to using files in other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach similar to browsers when they download stuff, i.e. transfer the file with a specific suffix e.g. `$fileName + '.wip'` and after transferring the file you simply remove the suffix.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention, Im concerned with users moving files in that I dont have control over via Windows Explorer. Once I know they are good to transfer, then I have all that covered, but I need to discover if they are infact good to transfer